# D3 line not displaying

Tags: d3.js

The following code use to show a line graph but somehow I know cannot display the line and I don't know what is missing from the code. Where is this code wrong. Thank you. The code can be seen [here](https://jsbin.com/loxomi/edit?html,js,output).

```
var h = 350;
var w = 400;

monthlySales = [
  {"month":10, "sales":100},
  {"month":20, "sales":130},
  {"month":30, "sales":250},
  {"month":40, "sales":300},
  {"month":50, "sales":265},
  {"month":60, "sales":225},
  {"month":70, "sales":180},
  {"month":80, "sales":120},
  {"month":90, "sales":145},
  {"month":100, "sales":130}
];

var lineFun = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return d.month*3;})
    .y(function(d) { return h-d.sales;})
    .interpolate("linear");

var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg").attr({
              width:w,
              height:h
            });

var viz = svg.append("path")
            .attr({
              d: lineFun(monthlySales),
              "stroke": "purple",
              "stroke-width": 2,
              "fill": "none"
            });
```

Comment: You just had an extra `})` at the bottom: https://jsbin.com/yaguqoloqu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thank you Geraldo. The page did not have scrolling to view the bottom and I totally didn't see it.